# Program to generate Armstrong like numbers (java)

Tags: java

> Armstrong like numbers are those which are equal to the sum of the cubes of their 1/3rd parts. For example:
>
> - \$165033 = 16^3 + 50^3 + 33^3\$
> - \$166500333 = 166^3 + 500^3 + 333^3\$

Here is my code, works fine, but I want to know how I can improve it:

Method check() checks if the number is armstrong like and generate() generates 6 digit armstrong like numbers.

```
class Armstronglike 
{
    static boolean check(long n)
    {
        String s = Long.toString(n);
        int l = s.length();
        if(l%3 !=0 )
        {
            return false; 
        }
        else
        {
            long sum =0; 
            long num = n; 
            long k = (long)Math.pow(10, s.length()/3);
            for(int i = 1; i<= 3; i++)
            {

                sum  = sum + (long)Math.pow((num%k), 3); 
                num  = num/k;  
            }
            if(sum == n)
            {
              return true; 
            }
            else
            return false; 
        }
    }
    static void generate() //to generate 6 digit armstrong numbers
    {
        System.out.println("6 digit armstrong numbers are: ");
        for(long i = 100000; i<1000000 ; i++)
        {
            if(check(i)== true)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: In your generator, instead of trying all the numbers, iterate on the three subparts. Keep in mind that the greatest of the three parts must be at least ((10^n)/3)^(1/3) where n is the number of digits you want, so 32 for n=6. You can keep the iteration on three increasing numbers, and then try all the permutations to find if one of them matches the sum. In this way complexity becomes n^(1/3) (something like 600 iterations instead of 10000000).

Comment: @N74 Please add an answer instead of a comment. Refer to the section **When _shouldn't_ I comment?** on [Comment everywhere](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).